# How use the function 'legendshrink' in Matlab2014b

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Today, I find a bug in Matlab2014b.
I use 'legendshrink' for plotting the figures, but it shows "Index exceeds matrix dimensions.", why ?
The following code:

```
  plot(1:10,'.-'); 
  plot(10:-1:1,'o-'); 
  legend({'one' 'two'},'location','north')
  legendshrink
```

The function 'legendshrink' is from http://github.com/wspr/matlabpkg/  .

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: It shows that "Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in legendshrink (line 104)
cch_min = find(cch==cch_lines(1));

Error in run_main (line 9)
    legendshrink"

Comment: I think it is a bug in Matlab2014b. It will be OK when I use Matlab 2012a.

Comment: It's not necessarily a bug in Matlab 2014b, but it is obviously different behaviour. Probably best to inform the author of the function, and/or do some debugging yourself.

Comment: You should have a  `hold on` between the `plot` commands, but I'm not sure if that is just a problem with your example code or not.

Comment: Can you help solve it? @David

Comment: The file you describe was uploaded in MATLAB file exchange to 2009, for version R2007a.  It's not a "bug" in that Mathworks will never guarantee that legacy, third-party functions are going to work for all versions of MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB 2014b introduced a new graphics framework. It looks like your `legendshrink` program is not compatible with the new framework, but works with the old one in 2012a. Perhaps you should contact the author and ask them to make some changes to support the new framework.

That's likely to be quite a big change: in the old framework, a legend was actually just an extra axis added to the plot. In the new framework, there's a completely new sort of object to represent legends.

Your error is coming from line 104, where the code looks for children of a legend axis of type `'Line'`. In the new framework, legend objects don't have any children of type `'Line'`, so `legendshrink` as it's currently implemented is not going to work at all.

To be clear, this is not a bug in MATLAB 2014b, it's that `legendshrink` is not compatible with MATLAB 2014b.